# Why are the Local and Network Service User Accounts Outside of my Computer's folder?

Tags: windows, security, user-accounts, domain

I am wondering why the Local and Network Service user accounts appear outside of my computer's folder.

In the image I linked below I show the Select User panel that popups after we've entered the security tab of a file/service's properties > Advanced > "Change" link next to the current owner's username > "Select User or Group" pop up, click Advanced one more time > Another "Select User or Group" window pops up > click the "Find Now" button, and a list of users comes up. The list of users has two columns, "Name" and "In Folder."

[A Computer's File or Service, right click and select Properties -> Security Tab -> Edit -> Advanced -> Find Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCMD9.png)

In the linked image, all users appear to be "In Folder" DESKTOP-myPC, with the exception of Local Service and Network Service; these have a blank folder, or no folder.

```
Name                | In Folder
------------------------------
Administrator         DESKTOP-MyPC
DefaultAccount        DESKTOP-MyPC
LOCAL SERVICE   
NETWORK SERVICE 
MyAccount             DESKTOP-MyPC
WDAGUtilityAccount    DESKTOP-MyPC
```

What is the meaning of this? or why is it that these two accounts are not in DESKTOP-myPC folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accounts like "MyAccount" or "Administrator" are domain-specific; they have SIDs unique to each domain. (When the computer isn't in a central domain, it acts like it is its own domain, so the SIDs are then unique to each computer.)

In other words, `MyPC\Administrator` on one computer (with SID S-1-5-*1234-2345-3456*-500) is different from `FriendPC\Administrator` on another computer (with SID S-1-5-*9876-8765-7654*-500), and if you add *your* local Administrator to the ACL of some file on a USB stick, it won't be recognized on other systems.

Meanwhile, built-in principals like "LOCAL SERVICE" are *not* domain-specific; instead they're in a virtual "NT AUTHORITY" domain, and each of them has the same fixed SID everywhere.

For example, `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE` is always S-1-5-19 on any system. If you add it to a file's ACL, it'll be recognized as LOCAL SERVICE anywhere the file goes. (It's a bit like "localhost", where each machine has its own 127.0.0.1.)

Take a look at these pages:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I look at the Regitry's HKEY_USERS, I recognized the NT AUTHORITY's SID. Mine appears like S-1-5-21-randomnum1-randomnum2-randomnum3-1001. I am the owner account of this personal PC, which is not networked, and I am wondering why the account is not like "S-1-5-21-<machine>-500"

Comment: That's the SID of your own account. The built-in "Administrator" always has RID 500, other users start at RID 1000+. (Even if your account is *an* admin account, it is still not *the* Administrator account.)